# Why is my request body empty?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I recently started learning the MEAN stack and I have encountered a problem. I am trying to send an $http.get request from angular to my local server but the request body is undefined. What's peculiar is that it is not undefined in my post. I am aware that the issue might be the body-parser and I have spent a couple hours trying to figure it out to no avail. Thanks for your help!

Here is my express code:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose= require('mongoose');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var http=require('http');
var db=mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/checkIt');



var server = express();
var Schema= mongoose.Schema;



server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

server.use(bodyParser.json());


server.use(express.static(__dirname));



var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});

var User=mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);


server.post("/checkIt/users",function(req,res){

    var newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    newUser.save(function(err,doc){
        res.send("inserted");
    });

});

server.get("/checkIt/users",function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    var userToCheck= new User({
        username:req.body.username,
        password:req.body.password
    });

    User.findOne({username: userToCheck.username, password: userToCheck.password},function(err,obj){
        res.send(obj);
    });

});
server.listen(3000);
```

Here is my loginController where I have my get request:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('loginController',['$scope','$location', '$http',function($scope,$location,$http){


    $scope.checkIfUser = function(){
        var user={
            username:$scope.username,
            password:$scope.password
        };

        $http.get("http://localhost:3000/checkIt/users",user)
            .success(function(response){
                if(response===""){
                    console.log("User does not exist");
                }
                else goToHome();
            });
    };

    var goToHome = function(){
        $location.path('/Home')
    }

}]);
```

Lastly, I do not know if this will help or not but this is the code snippet of where I do my $http.post request

```
$scope.signup = function(){
            createUser();
            console.log(user);
            $http.post("http://localhost:3000/checkIt/users",user)
            .success(function(response){
                console.log(response);
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't going to be a body for a `GET`! This is just how life is. No body for `GET`. Now to solve the problem. You want to use `req.query` on the server side to access the values.

On the Angular side you need to make a slight change to your code (sending passwords in urls is a bad thing):

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/checkIt/users', {
    params: { username: $scope.username, password:$scope.password } 
}).success(... same as before);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I ended up using req.query to access the values because params was giving me undefined. I will read a bit into it to find out why and yeah no worries, this is for learning purposes, I will not be sending passwords in urls in the future. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're correct `about req.query` - sorry. `req.params` is for parameter routes like `/users/:userId`. `req.params.userId` would contain the user id. I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The request body is undefined simply because you can't pass params through a `GET` request, you'll probably want to change your route name and use a `POST` request instead.

By the way, it may be cleaner to move your API requests in a `UserService` and inject it in your controller because you will eventually need to re-use them somewhere else.